# Dynamic html table but header is coming at bottom

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create Dynamic html table but header is coming at bottom. Can anyone please check my code and help me out to fix the issue.

```
<table id="queryResult" border="1">
  <tr>
      <th id="header1">Name</th>
      <th id="header2">Number Of Employees</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">      
 function soqlQuery(){          
      try{                      
          var table       = document.getElementById("queryResult");   

          sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
          var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name, NumberOfEmployees from Account",{
              onSuccess : function(result){
                  var records         = result.getArray("records");                       
                  for(var i = 0; i <records.length; i++){
                      var row         = table.insertRow(0);
                      var cell1       = row.insertCell(0);
                      var cell2       = row.insertCell(1);
                      cell1.innerHTML = records[i].Name;
                      cell2.innerHTML = records[i].NumberOfEmployees;
                  }        
              },
              onFailure : function(error){
                  alert('In failure - '+ error);
              }
          });
      }catch(e){
          alert(e);
      }
   }
  window.onload=function(){
      soqlQuery();
  }
  </script>
```

I am tying to get a database result in JS and from JS itself i am trying to display the result.

Comment: every time you are inserting the row at 0. so the header is at the bottom as it is inserted first and rest all after it and on top of it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` instead?

```
<table id="queryResult" border="1">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th id="header1">Name</th>
       <th id="header2">Number Of Employees</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tablebody">

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Then you can just append your mysql results to your `<tbody>` by selecting the `<tbody>` instead of the `<table>`.

```
var tablebody = document.getElementById("tablebody");
```

Comment: `tr` should be a child of `thead` and not the other way round

Comment: You're right. I noticed after I had posted it. Thanks